# What builds are using a specific build agent

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My company has a bunch of different builds and half a dozen different build agents, and I need to update some software for one of the builds. I don't want to break any other builds that are using said agent. I would like to get a list of all builds that use said agent so that I can validate them after my software updates on the agent. I would prefer not to individually review each build, as there are dozens, if not hundreds of them. Is there some way to get this information quickly? Either from the agent, or from TFS somehow?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I assume you're using tags to isolate certain builds to certain agents? If that's the case, you should be able to query the build definitions via the TFS API and extract the process template parameters.

Comment: So, I asked the wrong question. Controller level is enough for me. I didn't know that the TFS API existed. It does exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, builds are tied to controllers, not agents and could therefore run on any of the agents bound to the controller. Unless as suggested by Daniel Mann, you have your builds tagged to specific agents you won't be able to get that level of detail. Without tagging, your report would be limited to a list of machines that each build could possibly run on.

What I do in this situation is to have a separate, private build controller for build software testing. Upgrade the software on this and then queue test builds for the affected definitions, changing the controller to your test controller in the Queue Build parameters. Once you've verified that your changes won't break the builds you can then schedule downtime to upgrade the production agent machines.